# Let a,b,k be positive integers such that $a^2 mod k = b^2 mod k$, Then, $a mod k = b mod k$

Tags: real-analysis

I have tried to do a proof by contrapositive and contradiction but keep on getting stuck. What would be the right approach here?

Comment: do you mean to say $a^2 \equiv b^2 (\mod k)$ and $a \equiv b (\mod k)$

Comment: No I said the problem correctly, as Ross pointed out the statement was false which I missed.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true.  $1^2 \pmod 3 \equiv 2^2 \pmod 3$  More generally if $a =k-b$ you will have $a^2 \equiv b^2 \pmod k$.  It comes from $(-1)^2=1$

Comment: Would just a simple counter-example suffice then? Thanks for the answer... it is probably why I was making very little progress.

Comment: If you are asked to prove something is true and you find a counter-example the thing you are asked to prove is not true.  Report that and you are done.  Unless your axioms are inconsistent it is hard to prove things that are not true.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
All uses of
$\equiv$ are
$\bmod k$.

If
$a^2 \equiv b^2
$
then
$0
\equiv a^2 - b^2
\equiv (a-b)(a+b)
$.

This immediately shows that
$a \equiv b$
and
$a \equiv -b$
are solutions.

However,
more solutions appear
if the prime factors of $k$
are split.

For example,
if $k = pq$
where $p$ and $q$
are odd primes,
then
$a+b \equiv p,
a-b\equiv q$,
or
$a \equiv (p+q)/2,
b \equiv (p-q)/2$
is a solution.

Note that
$2(\frac{k+1}{2})
=k+1
\equiv 1
$,
so, $\bmod k$,
dividing by $2$
is the same as
multiplying by
$\frac{k+1}{2}$.